# Problem in understanding BI Publisher report rtf template

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I am new to BI Publisher reporting. I am seeing a rtf template file for a report that is run in Oracle APEX. I downloaded this template file from "Report Layouts" section of "Shared Components" from an APEX Application.

The problem is I don't understand the meaning of an element in the .rtf file. The element is:

<?variable@incontext:g1pos;position()?><?variable@incontext:g1;current-group()?>

This expression has a display text property = 'V'. So in the template I only see 'V' on its place but when I check the BI Properties for this element, I see the expression that I gave above.

when the report is executed, I don't see anything corresponding to this element. And when I google for variables in .rtf report templates, I see a syntax <xsl:variable name=,... to define a variable

Hence I don't understand the meaning of above expression, and what its purpose is... Can someone please help??

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky to explain, I have only used in in templates. The variables are reset in a loop or template.

```
<?variable@incontext:g1pos;position()?>
```

Get the value of position() and sets it to g1pos. I am assuming there is a for-each or template command just before this line. It is just a way of setting variables.

To see the value of the variable, try printing it with the $ command before the for-each loop closes.

```
<?for-each-group:G_EMPBANK;./DEP?>
<?variable@incontext:DEPT_ID;M_DEPT_ID?>
<?$DEPT_ID?>
<?end for-each-group?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; can you please also tell what is meant by "@incontext"? what is the purpose of this ?

Comment: Hi All experts! can someone else please reply to my last comment. I am still not clear about the last answer. I want a little more explanation.

Comment: I also need info about different functions that we can use to assign values to variables. For example one function is 'position()', if someone can let me know about other useful functions, or point me to a link where I can get this info, that will be great.